# Combine 2 logical disks into 1

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, raid

I'm running Windows 7 with a single 80GB SSD. I'm sick of running out of space. I want to get an additional SSD and set it up so that it's one contiguous system drive. Is this possible? Do I need a Raid controller and if so is this going to kill all my performance gain of having SSD drives?

Comment: A RAID-0 with two SSDs disks would give you a more performance than you have now. It's limited by the speed of the SATA connection (that's why PCIe gets used with faster disks). The TRIM command may not work over RAID.

Comment: I know this is possible using dynamic NTFS partitons, but I don't know exactly how to implement it...

Answer (score 1):

you can have Windows 7 and Vista (depending on versions) span multiple physical disks into one volume using using [dynamic disks](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-are-basic-and-dynamic-disks), but I do not know what kind of performance impact/gain would be attributed to doing this through the OS rather than a dedicated RAID controller.

Bare in mind that any spanned volume, whether handled in hardware or software, will increase your chances of a fatal data loss as the loss of one drive will invalidate all the data on both.

Comment: By doing this, though, the OP should know that he's doubling his chance of catastrophic data loss.

Comment: @ErikA same with any simple spanned volume though, whether in software or hardware. but i have updated my answer.

Comment: @Xantec precisely.

Comment: I'm not really concerned about data loss. It's just a dev box so if the HD fails I'll just rebuild it.

Comment: Hes looking for raid 0. Lot of info here: http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/132877/how_to_set_up_raid_on_your_pc.html

Comment: @Jeff F. The article deals with fake-raid, which seems to combine the disadvantages of SW and HW RAID (you gain no speed since the SW must do the work, and when you switch the HW *or* the OS you lose).

Comment: @ErikA, just for teh lulz, it's the data on the disk that determines whether or not the data loss was catastrophic ;)